# How to combine try/except in python into a pretty one liner?

Tags: python, python-2.7, append, try-catch, except

In order to make CSV files with many columns, I have many, **many** instances of

```
try:
  printlist.append(text['data'])
except:
  printlist.append('')
```

Is it possible to condense these 4 lines into 1 or 2 (mostly for easier reading of the code)? I've tried with this function but I haven't discovered a way to pass something that doesn't exist.

```
def tryexcept(input):
    try:
        printlist.append(input)
    except:
        printlist.append('')

    return printlist
```

**UPDATE** I should mention that 'text' is actually a dict value, so it should look like

```
printlist.append(text['data'])
```

(changed above)

Comment: What do you mean to "pass something" that doesn't exist?

Comment: perhaps an if statement in the function call?

Comment: what is the exception when you do `printlist.append(text)`? What are the problematic `text` objects?

Comment: `printlist.append(text)` should never throw an exception unless `text` or `printlist` is not declared. I think you have another problem than this exception.

Comment: @RickyA sorry, it's a dict value that I'm trying to append. I updated the original post.

Comment: Is it possible to replace the `text` dict with a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)?

Comment: @psny: added an answer for a normal dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
printlist.append(text['data'] if 'data' in text else '')
```

Or even better as @bruno desthuilliers suggested:

```
printlist.append(text.get('data',''))
```

[EDIT]

For nested dict I normally use my dict selector:

```
class TokenDataType:
    LIST = "list"
    DICT = "dict"

def _select_key(keyitt, data):
    try:
        new_key = keyitt.next()
    except StopIteration:
        return data
    if new_key["t"] == TokenDataType.DICT:
        return _select_key(keyitt, data[new_key["k"]])
    elif new_key["t"] == TokenDataType.LIST:
        return _select_key(keyitt, data[new_key["i"]])

def tokenize_query(query):
    tokens = []
    for token in query.split("."):
        token = token.strip()
        if token:
            ttype = TokenDataType.LIST if "[" in token else TokenDataType.DICT
            if ttype == TokenDataType.LIST:
                index = None
                if len(token) >= 3:
                    index = int(token.replace("[", "").replace("]", ""))
                tokens.append({"k":token, "t":ttype, "i":index})
            else:
                tokens.append({"k":token, "t":ttype})
    return tokens

def normalize_query(query=None, tokens=None):
    if tokens == None:
        tokens = tokenize_query(query)
    return ".".join([token["k"] for token in tokens])

def select(query, data, throw_exception_on_key_not_found=False):
    tokens = tokenize_query(query)
    try:
        return _select_key(iter(tokens), data)
    except Exception as e:
        if throw_exception_on_key_not_found:
            raise e
        return None

DQ = select

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = {"bla":1, "foo":{"bar":2}, "baz":[{"x":1}, {"x":2}]}
    print(DQ(".bla", test))
    print(DQ("bla", test))
    print(DQ("nothere", test))
    print(DQ(".foo", test))
    print(DQ("foo.bar", test))
    print(DQ("baz", test))
    print(DQ("baz.[0]", test))
    print(DQ("baz.[1].x", test))
    print(DQ("baz.[2].x", test))
```

for your case (appends `None` when one of the keys is not found):

```
printlist.append(DQ("data.someotherkey.yetanotherkey", text))
```

Comment: yes, thank you. very simple once I included the dictionary part.

Comment: What about reading the doc for `dict` and using `text.get('data', '')` instead ?

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers: This was the first that popped into mind. Will include yours for completeness.

Comment: what do you do if the value is two dict keys away? for example: text['data']['user']

Answer (score 2):

There's a dictionary method that does exactly this, and it let's you specify any default value.

```
input = text.get('data', default='')

printlist.append(input)
```

It checks if the key exists in the dictionary, and if not, it returns the default value. More on dictionaries [here](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict).

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple wrapper:

```
def execute_with_exception_handling(f):
    try:
        return f()
    except:
        raise
```

Then you execute your function:

```
def my_func():
    return 0 / 0

execute_with_exception_handling(my_func)
```

You can also add arguments to the function with `*args`. And you can even use decorators...that you can google because I recall off the top of my head how that works.

Comment: @psny: That is where the 'raise' is for ;) Replace that with something more useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to pass something that does not exist?

You can simply call function if the value that is being passed in is not "None" (Or any other unwanted value).

```
tryexcept( x ) if x is not None else None
```

Edit:
Are you are trying to see if the variable is declared or not? If yes, one way to get around this would be to declare the variable beforehand:

```
x = None
...
tryexcept( x ) if x is not None else None
```

Comment: if it doesn't exist, I have to append something else to the list.

Comment: Are you are trying to see if the variable is declared or not?

Comment: it's not a variable but dict key/value